# OpenTK bind buffer memory

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I am working on an application that uses OpenTK to draw hundereds of thousands of 2D lines and polygons so the memory management is critically important, I noticed that once I call those methods for generating and buffering the data to GPU the memory increases with large amount of megabytes if i have large example:

```
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VBO);
GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, new IntPtr(sizeof(float) * 2 * item.Count), item.ToArray(), BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
```

Where item is the list that contains the vertices. the problem if I load many example together I may get out of memory exception.

Comment: Dealing with the available amount of memory is at the end of the day useless. Prefer to require an amount of, say, 1GB and do your rendering in chunks of data that need less than that 1GB.

Comment: As @Ripi2 suggests, but with a little more detail: split your data into multiple VBOs. In your render loop, `BindBuffer` each buffer in turn before drawing.

Comment: @3Dave The technical details depend on other estrategies. For example you can "clean" and then refill the same VBO, by `glBufferSubData`. Or [streaming](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming)

Comment: Might be the `ToArray()` call. This will generate a new array and old arrays will be cleaned up from time to time by the garbage collector. Try to call `GC.Collect()` after the call and see if this is really the root cause (this is not meant as a solution, just as a test).

Comment: @Ripi2 and that's fine if the problem is really running out of available memory. But, host-to-GPU transfers are slow and best avoided when possible.